# How to sort only a specific portion of a List?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I have a List of doubles in java and i want a result list with sorted with specific index in  ascending order.

```
List<Double> DList=new ArrayList();

testList.add(0.5);
testList.add(0.2);
testList.add(0.9);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.54);
testList.add(0.71);
testList.add(0.71);
testList.add(0.71);
testList.add(0.92);
testList.add(0.12);
testList.add(0.65);
testList.add(0.34);
testList.add(0.62);
testList.add(0.5);
testList.add(0.2);
testList.add(0.9);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.1);
testList.add(0.54);
```

I have to perform sorting from index 7.
how can i do that?

Comment: Do you want to leave the first 7 elements alone, but sort the rest of the list? (Just checking whether I understand this right)

Comment: 3 upvotes for a question which, with minimal reseach, has an answer in API documentation and a [dedicated section in Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) (Range-View Operation section specifically).

Comment: Do you need any more help with this, or does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 10):

- [List.subList(startIndex, endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) creates a "backed" collection which sees your original list, aka "proxy" I think.
- Collections.sort() will just sort the sub-list, any swaps will actually occur in the original list

The JavaDoc explains this more clearly than I can manage:

> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the
>   sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a
>   list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view
>   instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a
>   range of elements from a list

```
list.subList(from, to).clear();
```

Example using your original problem

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(0.5);
list.add(0.2);
list.add(0.9);
list.add(0.1);
list.add(0.1);
list.add(0.1);
list.add(0.54);
list.add(0.71);
list.add(0.71);
list.add(0.71);
list.add(0.92);
list.add(0.12);
list.add(0.65);
list.add(0.34);
list.add(0.62);
list.add(0.5);
list.add(0.2);
list.add(0.9);
list.add(0.1);
list.add(0.1);
list.add(0.1);
list.add(0.54);
Collections.sort(list.subList(7, list.size()));
```